# Create Lucene Document from XML

Tags: xml, lucene

I have an XML document and I want to index it to a Lucene Index. 
i.e.

```
<hello>
  <world>hi</world>
</hello>
```

I would expect to have a Field ( hello.world:"hi") in the document ( specifying an analyzer )

I always can parse that but I was wondering whether exist any tool to generate it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a "tool" (actually a full-blown database server) that does this automatically: [eXist](http://exist-db.org/exist/lucene.xml). If properly configured, this allows you to mix XQuery and Lucene full-text queries like

```
for $hit in collection("/db/my-stuff")//hello/world[ft:query("hi")]
  order by ft:score($hit)  (:uses Lucene scoring formula:)
  return $hit
```

Analyzers are specified in a per-document collection configuration file.

A more light-weight approach using Apache Digester is described in an (old) [IBM DeveloperWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-lucene/).

**EDIT** After having dealt with eXist for two years, I'd like to add that its Lucene integration is less than perfect. For simple queries, it usually works fine, but when full-text queries are performed in the middle of complicated XPath queries, it looks like the query optimizer gets confused and you may get either the wrong result or horrible performance. Maybe eXist 2.0 has fixed some of this, YMMV.